# Using std::enable_if in a parameters list

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

In C++, consider the following example:

```
template <typename first, typename... params> struct q;

template <typename first> struct q <first>
{
    q()
    {
        cout<<"x"<<endl;
    }
};

template <typename first, typename... params> struct q
{
    q()
    {
        cout<<"x";
        q <params...> ();
    }
};

int main()
{
    q <int, int> ();
    q <int, int, enable_if<true, bool>::type> ();
    // q <int, int, enable_if<false, bool>::type> ();
}
```

I defined a template struct that accepts an arbitrary amount of parameters. I then instantiate it with a set of parameters. Each constructor will build a new q, with all its parameters but the first. A q with only one parameter won't call any more recursion.

Every time the constructor of a q is called, it will print out an "x". Therefore, the first line of the main will cause the program to print out "xx", while the second will print out an "xxx" since the enable_if is actually enabled. Now, I would have greatly appreciated if the third line would cause my program to print out "xx" (that is: build a q ). Sadly, what I get is the error

```
No template named 'type' in std::enable_if <false, bool>
```

What could I do to correct my example and make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need this? Writing `enable_if<false, bool>::type` necessarily yields a compiler error, so you cannot expect the compiler to somehow recover from it.

Comment: The third line has `true` in it, which doesn't correspond to the error shown. Also, `enable_if` has no SFINAE effect in this code if that's what you were hoping.

Comment: I need this because in a more serious part of my code I have some bytes and an object that is meant to parse them and extract some parameters that are specified in its parameters. As an example scanner `<unsigned int, bool, char> ()(bytes)` will extract an unsigned int, a bool and a char from my bytes. Now, I would like a switch to be able to add an unsigned int at the beginning of the parameters list, like `scanner <(if x is true then also unsigned int), unsigned int, bool char> scanner()(bytes)`

Comment: @0x499602D2 thank you, I fixed my typo. I am sorry but I have no idea on what you mean by SFINAE effect.

Comment: @MatteoMonti I'm not sure what the value of this is, but can't you just use some dummy class template instead of `enable_if`? Perhaps something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf2f0db6ac88ef48)?

Comment: Your example lacks a valid condition for enable_if (which should be used in a template for SFINAE, not in your way)

Comment: *Substitution Failure* is a necessary precondition for *Substitution Failure Is Not An Error* to occur.

Comment: ... and _Substitution_ is a necessary condition for _Substitution Failure_ to occur, which means you need to be in a template and the `enable_if` condition must depend on a template parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have misunderstood the use of `std::enable_if`. (Many of us did, to begin with).
This has led you to ask a technically misguided question instead of the more
general one you want answered. The question you want answered is *How can my template use or
ignore a template argument, based only a compiletime condition?*, and it's not
a bad one.

You have the impression that `std::enable_if<Cond,T>::type` is a template expression 
that will instantiate to `T` when `Cond` is `true` and will instantiate to *nothing* when 
`Cond` is false.

That is correct when `Cond` is `true`, because `std::enable_if<true,T>` is defined like:

```
std::enable_if<true,T> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

But `std::enable_if<false,T>` is defined like:

```
std::enable_if<false,T> {};
```

See those definitions [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Hence `std::enable_if<false,T>::type` does not *disappear*; for any `T`,
it becomes an ill-formed, uncompilable, reference to the member-type `type` of
`std::enable_if<false,T>`, which does not exist. It becomes a compiler error.

Thus `std::enable_if` can be used to make instantiation of a template class or
function either possible or impossible based upon the compiletime value of some
boolean constant. And since the compiler will dismiss from consideration any
non-viable instantiation of a template, provided there is a viable alternative,
it can therefore be used to make a compiletime choice between alternative
implementations of a template class or function, based on such a condition, e.g.

```
template<bool Cond>
typename std::enable_if<Cond,int>::type foo(int i) // A
{
    return i*i;
}

template<bool Cond>
typename std::enable_if<!Cond,int>::type foo(int i) // B
{
    return i + i;
}
```

Here, `foo<some_bool_constant>(i)` will yield *i squared* if `some_bool_constant` is `true` and
*i doubled* if `some_bool_constant` is `false`, because in the first case
the `B` overload has an ill-formed instantiation and in the second case
it's the `A` overload that becomes ill-formed.

The alternative overloads give the compiler a choice of instantiations to consider
each time it sees `foo<some_bool_constant>(x)`, with one turning out ill-formed and the other viable,
depending on the truth-value of `some_bool_constant`. It picks the one that is viable in each case. This
behaviour is called [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), and that
is what you need to understand before you can understand `std::enable_if`.

But there are no alternative instantiations of your:

```
q <int, int, enable_if<false, bool>::type> ()
```

"depending on the value of *false*". *false* unconditionally means *false* and so this is just ill-formed
code.

And consider: Even if `std::enable_if<false,bool>::type` *did* somehow disappear, that would leave:

```
q <int, int, > ()
```

which is *still* ill-formed.

> What could I do to correct my example and make it work?

It doesn't take much, in fact, and `std::enable_if` does not feature. Let's address the real question: *How can my template use or
ignore a template argument, based only a compiletime condition?*

You need to define your template `q<First, ... Rest>` and some other template `accept_if<bool Cond, typename T>` in such a way
that for any instantiation of `q`:

```
/*(Iq)*/    q<A0,....,Aj,....,Ak>  // 0 <= j <= k
```

where `Aj` = `accept_if<some_bool_constant,t>::type`, then if `some_bool_constant` == `true`,
**(Iq)** will have exactly the same effects as:

```
q<A0,....,t,....,Ak>
```

and if `some_bool_constant` == `false` then
**(Iq)** will have the same effects as:

```
q<A0,....,Ak>
```

*without resorting to any runtime test of `some_bool_constant`*. (In **(Iq)**,
the '....' are just schematic place-holders for possible arguments: nothing to do
with C++ packs or elipses.)

But `accept_if<some_bool_constant,t>::type` must resolve to some *type specifier* at compiletime
or the code is ill-formed. It cannot resolve to nothing. So in the `false` case it must resolve to a type
specifier that the instantiation of **(Iq)** will handle as specifying *no data-type*.

Now the compelling utility of possessing a type specifier that specifies *no data-type*
in C/C++ was recognized as long ago as the very first ANSI Standard for C. That
type specifier is `void`.

From your comments we learn that the template parameters of `q`
represent a sequence of data types which an instantiation of the constructor shall extract
from a source passed by argument. In that case, `void` ideally fits the bill
as a type specifer denoting *nothing to be done*. You cannot declare a `void` object,
let alone extract one from somewhere.

Hence I suggest that your `accept_if` be defined:

```
template<bool Cond, typename T>
using accept_if = std::conditional<Cond,T,void>::type;
```

i.e. `accept_if<true,T>` = `T` and `accept_if<false,T>` = `void`. Read about
[std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

With this definition, you then have only to add to your existing specializations
of `q` one more:

```
template<> struct q<void> {};
```

giving `q<void>` a default constructor that does nothing. Here is a sample program
like your own, but well-formed, that illustrates this solution:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<bool Cond, typename T>
using accept_if = typename std::conditional<Cond,T,void>::type;

template <typename first, typename... params> struct q;

template<> struct q<void> {};

template <typename first> struct q <first>
{
    q()
    {
        std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename first, typename... params> struct q
{
    q()
    {
        std::cout << "x";
        q<params...>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    q<int, int>();
    q<int, int, accept_if<true,bool>>();
    q<int, int, accept_if<false,bool>>();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is what you wanted:

```
xx
xxx
xx
```

In a different scenario it is possible that you would want even `Aj` = `void`
*not* to be ignored in **(Iq)**. But since we can create types at will, you can
always a create a type that is by fiat different from all those that your template
must not ignore, say: `struct ignore {};` Then you would define:

```
template<bool Cond, typename T>
using accept_if = std::conditional<Cond,T,ignore>::type;
```

and specialize:

```
template<> struct q<ignore> {};
```

Comment: One of the most detailed answers I have ever received on StackOverflow. Thank you very much, now everything is much more clear!

Answer (score 0):

`enable_if` is meant to be used in a context where [SFINAE](http://accu.org/content/conf2013/Jonathan_Wakely_sfinae.pdf) can be used, which means inside a template.

In a non-template context (or a context that doesn't depend on template parameters) when the condition is false it is an error to refer to `enable_if<false, T>::type` because that member doesn't exist.

> What could I do to correct my example and make it work?

I don't understand what you're trying to do. What do you expect `enable_if<false, bool>::type` to be? There is no such type, how do you think you can use it?

Comment: Basically, I am looking for a more compact version of the following:`if(b /* b being a template parameter, so it is known at compile time */) q <int, int> (); else q <int, int, bool> ();`

Comment: @MatteoMonti: You can use a class template other than `enable_if`, even one of your own - after all its purpose is just to hold a boolean value and a type as template parameters (if I understand your use case correctly).

Comment: @MatteoMonti, you can't use `enable_if` to change the number of template arguments. `<int, int, enable_if<false, bool>::type>` still has three arguments, but the third argument is ill-formed and gives an error. `q<X, Y, Z>` has three template arguments, period. There is no way to make `Z` maybe exist and maybe not exist. The shortest way to do it with only standard library facilities is probably `std::conditional<b, q<int, int>, q<int, int, bool>>::type`